# Value of type 'URL' has no member 'URLByAppendingPathComponent'

Tags: ios, swift, cordova

I am working on a cordova app and trying to convert the swift code it generated to swift 3 syntax because it is producing errors when I try to build it. I have this function

```
init(configuration: WebAppConfiguration, versionsDirectoryURL: URL, initialAssetBundle: AssetBundle) {
  self.configuration = configuration
  self.versionsDirectoryURL = versionsDirectoryURL
  self.initialAssetBundle = initialAssetBundle

  downloadDirectoryURL = versionsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("Downloading")

  queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.meteor.webapp.AssetBundleManager", attributes: [])

  downloadedAssetBundlesByVersion = [String: AssetBundle]()
  loadDownloadedAssetBundles()

  let operationQueue = OperationQueue()
  operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
  operationQueue.underlyingQueue = queue

  // We use a separate to download the manifest, so we can use caching
  // (which we disable for the session we use to download the other files 
  // in AssetBundleDownloader)
  session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: operationQueue)
}
```

Line 6

```
downloadDirectoryURL = versionsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("Downloading")
```

is throwing an error

**Value of type 'URL' has no member 'URLByAppendingPathComponent'**

and I do not understand what is causing this error, I have looked through swift 3 documentation as well as other answers online, but the line is supposed to be error free, please any insight into resolving this error would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5):

There is an 'appendingPathComponent' method for type 'URL'

Make sure you didn't do the mistake I did of calling the method for a variable of type [URL]

```
let documentURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: 
.userDomainMask)
        let fileURL = 
documentURL.appendingPathComponent("tempImage.jpg")
```

fixed by making sure it's a variable of type URL

```
let documentURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let fileURL = documentURL.appendingPathComponent("tempImage.jpg")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's `appendPathComponent` not `appendingPathComponent`, simply retype it will suggest you the correct syntax

Comment: This did not work, it says "Cannot use mutating member on immutable value:'versionsDirectoryURL' is a 'let' constant. Even after I changed the let to a var, this error still persissts

Comment: it will work if you change to var, try rebuild your project, you should add something like `var versionsDirectoryURL = versionsDirectoryURL ` since it's function param

Comment: @Tj3n It's [`appendingPathComponent`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/url/1780239-appendingpathcomponent) and `appendPathComponent` will append the pathComponent to self but OP is using the result.

Comment: @NiravD ah yeah, didn't notice that, then the syntax seems correct, still not sure why he got that error?

Comment: This init function is inside a class called "AssetBundleManager" if that helps any, literally the only error in my codebase now and makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax swift 4+ is:

```
        let VideoFilePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("mergeVideo\(arc4random()%1000)d")?.appendingPathExtension("mp4").absoluteString
```